# How do I make enemies drop money after they die?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm looking to make some enemies in my game drop "UP Points" (Upgrade Points in the form of small yellow squares) when I shoot them. I've tried a few different things but can't seem to figure out how to spawn these collectable points in place of where an enemy just died. Does anyone have any ideas about how I could implement this?

UP class:

```
class Up(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([5, 5])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Here's the loop for when an enemy gets shot and dies:

```
for bullet in bullet_list: #For each bullet:
        # Whenever a bullet collides with a zombie,
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, zombie_list, True)
        for i in block_hit_list:
            # Destroy the bullet and zombie and add to the score
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            score += 100
```

Sorry for not posting my whole code, the main game loop is at the bottom :)

```
import pygame
import math
import random

BLACK  = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE  = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN  = (0, 255, 0)
RED    = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE   = (0, 0, 255)
ORANGE = (255, 119, 0)
ZOMBIE_GREEN = (122, 172, 34)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

cursor_x = 100
cursor_y = 100

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()

        # pygame.Surface will create a rectangle with the width and height given
        # and the command below it tells it to fill it in with that color
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # This defines the starting position (x, y)
        # of whatever sprite is passed through
        self.rect.x = 600
        self.rect.y = 300

        # This is the current speed it will move when drawn
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.walls = None

    # Defines how the player will move
    def movement(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y


    # Updates the information so the screen shows the player moving
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        self.rect.y += self.change_y

        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos_x = self.rect.x = random.randrange(35, screen_width - 35)
        self.pos_y = self.rect.y = random.randrange(35, screen_height - 135)

        # How Zombies move towards player

    def update(self):
        zombie_vec_x = self.rect.x - player.rect.x
        zombie_vec_y = self.rect.y - player.rect.y
        vec_length = math.sqrt(zombie_vec_x ** 2 + zombie_vec_y ** 2)

        if self.rect.x != player.rect.x and self.rect.y != player.rect.y:
            zombie_vec_x = (zombie_vec_x / vec_length) * 1 # These numbers determine
            zombie_vec_y = (zombie_vec_y / vec_length) * 1 # zombie movement speed

        self.pos_x -= zombie_vec_x
        self.pos_y -= zombie_vec_y

        self.rect.x = self.pos_x
        self.rect.y = self.pos_y


        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, sprites_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.rect.x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            elif self.rect.x < 0:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right
            elif self.rect.y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom       

class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

class Cursor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.groups = all_sprites_list
        self._layer = 1

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(RED)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.walls = None

    # This updates the cursor to move along with your
    # mouse position (defined in control logic)
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x = cursor_x
        self.rect.y = cursor_y

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([8, 8])
        self.image.fill(ORANGE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Instead of using the rect. positions, we'll use pos_ variables
        # to calculate position. This is because the rect. uses integers
        # while a variable can have exact float numbers. This will keep
        # the bullets trajectory exact istead of useing a general
        # (rounded) whole number <3
        self.pos_x = player.rect.x + 4  # Set up pos_x and pos_y here
        self.pos_y = player.rect.y + 4  # rather than rect.x and rect.y

        self.walls = None
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

        speed = 6
        bullet_vec_x = (cursor.rect.x - 4) - player.rect.x
        bullet_vec_y = (cursor.rect.y - 4) - player.rect.y
        vec_length = math.sqrt(bullet_vec_x ** 2 + bullet_vec_y ** 2)
        bullet_vec_x = (bullet_vec_x / vec_length) * speed
        bullet_vec_y = (bullet_vec_y / vec_length) * speed
        self.change_x += bullet_vec_x
        self.change_y += bullet_vec_y

    def update(self):
        self.pos_x += self.change_x  # Update pos_x and pos_y. They will become floats
        self.pos_y += self.change_y  # which will let them maintain sub-pixel accuracy.

        self.rect.x = self.pos_x # Copy the pos values into the rect, where they will be
        self.rect.y = self.pos_y # rounded off. That's OK since we never read them back.



pygame.init()

screen_size = pygame.display.Info()

size = (1300, 720)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

#size = (screen_size.current_w, screen_size.current_h)
#screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
#    ((screen_size.current_w, screen_size.current_h)),pygame.FULLSCREEN
#    )

screen_width = screen_size.current_w
screen_height = screen_size.current_h

pygame.display.set_caption("Zombie Shooter")



wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
zombie1_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Walls are made here = (x_coord for where it starts,
# y_coord for where it starts, width of wall, height of wall)
# These walls are made with fullscreen dimentions, not any set dimentions
# Left
wall = Wall(BLUE, 0, 0, 10, screen_height)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)
# Top
wall = Wall(BLUE, 0, 0, screen_width, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)
# Bottom
wall = Wall(BLUE, 0, screen_height - 10, screen_width, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)
# Right
wall = Wall(BLUE, screen_width - 10, 0, 10, screen_width)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)
# HUD Border
wall = Wall(BLUE, 0, screen_height - 100, screen_width, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)

# This creates the actual player with the parameters set in ( ).
# However, we must add the player to the all_sprites_list
# so that it will actually be drawn to the screen with the draw command
# placed right after the screen.fill(BLACK) command.
player = Player(WHITE)
player.walls = wall_list
all_sprites_list.add(player)

zombie = Enemy(ZOMBIE_GREEN)
zombie.walls = wall_list
for i in range(5):
    zombie = Enemy(ZOMBIE_GREEN)
    all_sprites_list.add(zombie)
    zombie1_list.add(zombie)
    sprites_list.add(zombie)

cursor = Cursor(7, 7)
cursor.walls = wall_list
all_sprites_list.add(cursor)

bullet = Bullet()

font = pygame.font.SysFont("crushed", 30)

score = 0
up_score = 0

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:

    # --- Main event loop ---
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        # Press 'P' to quit the game_____
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                done = True
        #________________________________

        # Keyboard controls. The numbers inside change the speed of the player
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.movement(-4, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.movement(4, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.movement(0, -4)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.movement(0, 4)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.movement(4, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.movement(-4, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.movement(0, 4)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.movement(0, -4)
        # ___________________________________________________________________

        # Mouse Controls----------------------------
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        cursor_x = pos[0]
        cursor_y = pos[1]

        if cursor_x <= 10:
            cursor_x = 10
        if cursor_x >= (screen_width - 17):
            cursor_x = (screen_width - 17)

        if cursor_y <= 10:
            cursor_y = 10
        if cursor_y >= (screen_height - 107):
            cursor_y = (screen_height - 107)

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullet = Bullet()
            all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
            bullet_list.add(bullet)
        #--------------------------------------------

    all_sprites_list.update()

    # How bullets vanish when they hit a sprite or a wall______________________
    for bullet in bullet_list: #For each bullet:
        # Whenever a bullet collides with a zombie,
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, zombie1_list, True)
        for i in block_hit_list:
            # Destroy the bullet and zombie and add to the score
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            score += 100


    for bullet in bullet_list:
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, wall_list, False)
        for i in block_hit_list:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    cursor.update()
    bullet_list.update()
    sprites_list.update()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)


    screen.fill(BLACK)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    text = font.render("Score: " + str(score), True, WHITE)
    screen.blit(text, [30, screen_height - 64])

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Make sure they're holding out the money first. Loss of electrical impulse to the muscle, and gravity will take care of the rest :P

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Lol I appreciate the humor but I'd like an actual answer xD

Comment: To be perfectly honest, game design isn't my thing. It's pretty late where I am, so I figured I'd end the night on a humorous note. Good luck :)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Haha well thanks anyway!

Comment: I don't really understand what you're confused about. You've already got logic that spawns bullets (presumably near a player sprite), and logic to test if they collide with the enemies. Why not use essentially the same logic to spawn the upgrade items? They spawn near the enemy just before it dies, and check for collisions with the player (to be collected).

Comment: @ Blckknght Well the reason I'm so confused is I thought that it would be really easy (I already have logic for when an enemy dies so why can't I just spawn them with that code?) I tried a few different ways to spawn the coins but I couldn't get it to work. I'm mainly confused on how to draw it to the screen in the position where the zombies died. I thought it would be so easy but it's proving to be a little harder than I thought :/ I'm looking into Sloth's answer now, I'll let you know what I come up with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Up` class to accept an argument `pos`, and use it to set the starting position:

```
class Up(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([5, 5])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
```

Now, when you hit a zombie, create an `Up`, using the position of the zombie you just killed.

```
for bullet in bullet_list:
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, zombie_list, True)
    for i in block_hit_list:
        # just use .kill() to remove a Sprite from all of its Groups
        # kill() may get called multiple times, but that does not hurt
        bullet.kill() 
        score += 100
        # create an Up for each killed zombie
        # takes two arguments: color and pos
        # we call .add() to add the Sprite immediately to
        # the all_sprites_list and the up_list
        Up((255, 0, 0), i.rect.center).add(all_sprites_list, up_list)
```

You didn't show the rest of your code, but I guess you call `.draw` and `.update` on your `all_sprites_list` and create a `Group` called `up_list`.

Comment: Wow this works like a charm, thank you! For the sake of me understanding what's actually happening, the line `self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)` is taking the `up` image and centering it to the zombie, correct? And it does this because the `i.rect.center` argument for the Up class takes the center of the zombie (because that's what was added to the `block_hit_list`?) Just want to understand how it works. Thanks again!

Comment: When you call `get_rect` on a `Surface`, you get a `Rect` object with the topleft position being `0, 0` and the width/height of the `Surface`. Since the `x` and `y` properties of a `Rect` can also describe a position, the `Rect` class is used for keeping track of the position and drawing of Sprites (this is why a `Sprite` has a member called `rect`, which is an instance of the `Rect` class. The `Rect` class also has a bunch of useful properties, like `topleft`, `center` etc. When calling `get_rect`, you can pass keywords to directly set some of those properties (like I do here with `center`).

Comment: So when a zombie is killed, it's easy to get the position that is the center of its image, since the `rect` "describes" the position of the zombie. So we can make use of the `center` property here again, and passing it to the constructor of `Up`, which in turn sets the center of its own `Rect` to that exact position. You could also have used e.g. `topleft` or `buttomright`. For a full list of all avaiable properties, see the documentation.

Comment: Awesome man, thanks again for your help! High-fives all around

Answer (score 2):

What you will have to do is before you destroy the zombie sprite grab its location and draw the UP coin. Then make sure that whenever the player controlled sprite, in this case the bullet, upon contact "collects" the coin. I haven't worked with python that much but the main code would look something like this:

```
def drawCoin():  
    zombieCoords = grabZombieCoords()   
    drawSprite(zombieCoords())
```

This would essentially just get the coordinates of the zombie, destroy it, and then place the coin at the last known location of the zombie. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Plozzk So when you say "summon" the coin to the zombie coordinates, how do I do that? Do I need to use a `draw` command to place it there? How do I make the coin appear on the screen?

Comment: @Tanman1276 I guess you should be able to 'summon' them like how you are currently making bullets appear (at the coordinates of the player).

Comment: @Tanman1276 When I say summon you need to just use the draw method with the coordinates of the zombie. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Plozzk Awesome, thank you :) Would it be best to add the "up" coin to the `all_sprites_list` and have it be drawn when the `all_sprites_list.draw(screen)` command is issued or should I have a separate draw statement inside my collision code? Not sure if it would effect something wither way

Comment: @Tanman1276 I would suggest putting it into your collision code because if you draw it with everything else you might see it before you have killed a zombie. I would just suggest creating a function that is called from the collision code that will draw the sprite and add it to the bullets collision list.